# jquery ajax is converting ruby objects array into hash

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, arrays

So I have this weird problem with jquery doing a ajax post with a ruby object. I have 2 options.
1. $('form_id'}.serialize(). I know this works. But my form simply has too many fields, and it is a little too inconvenient to manage them in the form
2. Second option, the rails controller is constructing a ruby object along the way as the form is being edited. This is super convenient only if I can simply stick in the object in the ajax post request. Apparently I am able to, with something like this...

```
some_function() {
  $.ajax( {type: post, url: '/action', data: { 'post_data': <%= @ruby_object.to_json %> }});
}
```

If you wonder this works, it does. (dunno how and why)
But there is a small problem. the ruby object has a array of hashes within a hash, like this { [ {} ] } It appears that someone somewhere is converting that array to a hash with keys which are indices of that array. So in the action, if i print the parameters, I get { { {} } }. So can someone tell me how not to get this and get back exactly the original object structure?

Comment: can you post some of your Ruby code that is creating "ruby_object"?

Comment: What ruby web framework are you using?

Comment: `{ [ {} ] }` is not possible, hashes are key/value pairs, you can't just drop an array in the middle of it.

Comment: can you give us a more concrete example? ie what does the hash/array/hash look like with actual data (instead of when empty)?

Answer (score 0):

You do $.toJSON on your JS object, and post it as 'json' format. And if you're curious, how Rails converts the post data to Ruby object, check `actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb`